# terraform init failing in gitlab pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab, terraform

I am a newbie for gitlab and I have defined this pipeline defined but keeps failing with error. Help is greatly appreciated

```
$ terraform init -backend=false
/bin/sh: eval: line 118: terraform: not found
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

--see my pipeline

```yaml
image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
stages:
    - Test and Lint

Validate Terraform:
    stage: Test and Lint
    script:
        - echo "Validate Terraform"
        - cd infra/
        - apk update && apk add bash
        - terraform init -backend=false
        - terraform validate
        - terraform fmt -check
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^(dev|master|production)$/'
```

Comment: the name and entry point tags should be indented for image and also use the syntax -  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"]

Comment: Thank you Raman, tried your solution didn't work for me

Comment: Is `line 118` referring to a line in your code? If so, could you please highlight that line with a comment in your code snippet, since we don't see the same line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The image documentation states:

> The light version of this container will copy the current stable version of the binary into the container, and set it for use as the default entrypoint.

You are overriding the container's entrypoint and it looks like you are overwriting the PATH variable, so the terraform executable that you are trying to execute is not found.
Do not override the entrypoint, or make sure that the terraform executable's directory is included in the PATH variable.